# How can i use Multiple filter in wfst leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, wfs-t

I'm using wfst plugin in leaflet. I can send request just by one filter and get response correctly like this:

```
var layer = new L.WFS({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows',
            typeNS: sf,
            typeName: road,
            crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
            geometryField: 'geom',
            filter: new L.Filter.Within(values[0], values[1], values[2])},
            style: {
                color: 'blue',
                weight: 2
            }
        }).addTo(map)
```

How can I send two or more filter Simultaneously like this:

```
filter: new L.Filter.Within(values[0], values[1], values[2])}
filter: new L.Filter.EQ(values[0], values[1], values[2])}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should combine using the logic operator `AND` like below

```js
var condition1 = new L.Filter.EQ('city', 'Perm');
var condition2 = new L.Filter.EQ('city', 'Quest');
var combinedCondition = new L.Filter.And(condition1, condition2);
console.log(combinedCondition.toGml());
```

Comment: Docs are at https://github.com/Flexberry/Leaflet-WFST#filter for anyone else searching